# Creating a data displaying map

Tags: html, graphics, vector, dictionary, svg

How would one go about creating something like an 'election map'. i.e. a map of the country divided into areas which then turn one colour or the other based upon supporting data (which ideally is then viewable if the areas are clicked).
I want to do such a thing with users adding data and then their post code area turns one colour or the other depending on what users add.
I assume vector graphics are the way to go here: I've yet to do anything with html5 so that would be nice to investigate, I don't really want to get into flash. I've been told to try and modify google maps in some way but...this doesn't seem like it would work quite right and it feels like a cop out.
Any advice?

P.S: to make things even more complicated...is there anyway to make it so that items can be toggled on or off (e.g with the election map example, the locations of cities).
All I  can think is a seperate svg which overlays the map one but that may work unpredictably with zooming.

Answer (score 2):

My first piece of advice would be to not reinvent the wheel.  There are lots of useful libraries and infrastructure options, many of which are free (as in both beer and speech).

There are lots of options for the client side processing.  For the Javascript client you could use:

- [Bing Maps SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)
- [Google Maps SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
- [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/)
- [PolyMaps](http://polymaps.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)

Of these I would personally recommend OpenLayers as the most versatile and truly open client side framework.

This question on [GIS.StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/comparison-of-javascript-mapping-libraries) has further details of contenders in this area.

You are also going to have to have some provider of the geometry/geography of the map that you want to symbolise.  There are a number of options for this task, you would could use some sort of WMS (Web Map Service) of which the options are [many and varied](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service#Software) or you could supply files in some sort of spatial format like GML, KML or GeoJson.  GeoJson seems to be getting a lot of traction as both easy to use and reduced payload.

You may want to think about serving this from a backend [spatial database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_database_systems).  If you want to go this direction I have found PostGIS + GeoServer to be very good place to start but there are so many options and combinations.  The good thing is there are well established standards in this area.

Finally check out some of the [examples](http://thematicmapping.org/playground/openlayers_piecharts_geojson_google_chart.php) [of what](http://www.opengeohost.com/slcgeoexplorer/) [you could](http://afghanistanelectiondata.org/open) achieve.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 canvas Is recognized as NOT being useful for maps as it is just an arrangement of pixels and cannot be made to react to input
Vector graphics should be used for this type of application.
The event handlers you will need will probably be the mouse entering , mouse leaving and clicking the area the user is interested in.
As a practice go to the converter on my website

http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php

Create a tiny map in Inkscape and save as an SVG file and upload it to the above URL

Look at the output in th js window.

This might help you. If stuck leave a message...C

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a web mapping package - OpenLayers, for example - and then you just write the javascript to drive it. You can change the colour of features, you can toggle them on or off, you can do all sorts of overlays, popups, etc etc. It's All Just Javascript.

Pop over to www.openlayers.org and see what it can do.